# Format of saved tables in postgreSQL

Tags: format, postgresql-9.2

What is the format of saved schema and tables in Postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `pg_dump` to save the schema and tables, you have a choice of plain text (the default) or a few binary formats suitable for input to `pg_restore` - you can read all about them [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgdump.html).